# "Expected of" vs. "expected from"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

> - It is expected *of/from* you to find the solution.
> - Such rude behavior was not expected *of/from* you.

I am quite sure that *from* is the correct usage in both cases, but *of* could be used in the first one. Can somebody corroborate?

Comment: They're both valid, but "of" is far more common. Your first sentence is a bit stilted anyway - better would be *"It is expected that you find the solution"*.

Answer (score 12):

When you want to express the person who you expected would do something (as in the first example, and possibly the second too), one would normally use **of**. I would be inclined to say *from* is unidiomatic in your first sentence, especially because *it is expected of you* means "you are supposed/obliged to" here; where *expected* has this strong idiomatic sense of obligation, the agent should definitely have *of*:

> It is expected *of* you to find the solution.

When it is not the person who you expect will do something, i.e. if the person has a different connection to the verb (like the indirect object below), you should not use *of*, but the appropriate preposition, as you no doubt know:

> Such applause was not expected *for* our opponent.

If you use *of* here, it means that you did not expect our opponent to applaud like this. He becomes the agent:

> Such applause was not expected *of* our opponent.

---

In your second example, the situation is less clear.

> Such rude behavior was not expected *of* you.

The above is possible; it suggests to me that you were *not supposed* to exhibit such rude behaviour. But *from* is possible too, with a slightly different meaning:

> Such rude behavior was not expected *from* you.

This means to me that we were surprised to see this behaviour from you. It does not suggest "you were not supposed to" in itself; but the context adds this sense of obligation at any rate (one is always supposed not to exhibit rude behaviour).

Comment: +1 good distinction.  I might change "supposed to" to "obligated to" in your last paragraph.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks! Hmmm I deliberately mixed "supposed" and "obliged" to keep the meaning of *expected* in this sense a bit vague, which it is. Or do you think this is unclear? I am in doubt.

Comment: Per my comment, I think *expected of [pronoun] to* sounds stilted. As [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expected+of+him+to%2Cexpected+that+he%2Cexpected+that+he+should%2Cexpected+he+should&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows, we mostly use other forms, normally involving *"that he [should]"*.

Comment: But +1 for the duty/anticipation distinction, which is the primary issue here from OP's point of view.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I do not disagree with you about the stiltedness, but that wasn't really what the OP was interested in, so I didn't address it. Besides, some context can usually be found where it is acceptable, with an echo perhaps.

Comment: Agreed - in the end, I think *expected of [pronoun] to* constructions fall into the same general class as [think {pronoun} to be](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/). Plus there's your outstanding answer re [supposed to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/), which taken all together indicates OP is skating over some very thin ice with this question!

Answer (score 5):

I would typically use "from" when referring to something I expect to receive from someone. Such as "a performance report is expected from everyone". Whereas when I'm referring to behavioral  things that aren't "given" to anyone but "done" or "maintained", I would use "of". E.g. "attention to detail is expected of you."

However, I don't have any particular sources to corroborate that this IS indeed the rule. It just sounds more correct semantically to me.

Comment: Yes, rhetoric is, indeed, the only thing that needs rule. Expected of implies a movement of after-the-fact anticipation in the direction from the subject to the object of expectation Expected from implies movement from the object to the subject of expectation. I expect of you will have done as anticipated you should. I expect from you that the payment you promised will arrive in my hand from yours. Expected of operates as an abstract expression; expected from as a concrete expression.