# "Expect of" vs. "expect from"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expected of, or expected from someone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60927/expected-of-or-expected-from-someone)

Which of these two sentences is grammatically correct? Are both? What's the difference here?

> - What sort of work would be expected of me?
> - What sort of work would be expected from me?