# Does English allow a zero copula in subordinate clauses?

Tags: copular-verbs, zero-copula

In a casual search of the web, I found a few indications English does not allow zero copulas (https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1468).  However, I frequently see sentences with subordinate clauses that juxtapose a noun phrase with an adverb phrase, such as the following from a contemporary sci-fi author:

> Kai stares up at me from the grave, **his eyes hard as obsidian**.

If this clause were made into a sentence, it would take an obligatory verb:

> *His eyes hard as obsidian. 
>  His eyes are hard as obsidian.

The original clause seems to contain an implicit "to be."  Is it an example of a zero copula?  If not, what is this construction called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your definition of a *clause*. The traditional definition is "a finite verb and all its dependencies"; then your phrase is not a clause.

The construction is called an **[absolute construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction)**: a noun and an attribute together forming an adverbial constituent.

Comment: in the ablative case.

Comment: @JohnLawler: What?

Comment: Absolutive constructions are in the ablative case. "Ablative absolute"; surely you remember?

Comment: I can't wait until people start applying set theory to English...

Comment: @JohnLawler: Absolute constructions need not be in the ablative case. In Latin, they are, yes. In Greek, they're usually in the genitive, but sometimes in the accusative. In English, Dutch, and probably many other languages, they're normally in the nominative, as you can see. I have no idea why you mention the ablative.

Comment: @AK4749: Set theory is all over the place in English syntax and semantics. For instance, the phonosemantics of [_kl-_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: mind = blown... this is the coolest thing ever - do you have any more references I can start my exploration with?

Comment: I've always assumed there had to be due to the advances made in NLP, but I had no idea it was a rigorous development

Comment: The Wikipedia article "Nominative absolute" has some very similar sentence examples.  The "Absolute construction" article was broader.

Answer (score 5):

There are any number of situations in which *be* can be deleted (or, alternatively, prevented from appearing) in subordinate -- and even main -- clauses.

A very simple example is [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299), which applies to restrictive relative clauses, and deletes (as I will call it) the subject relative pronoun (the "Wh-" part) plus whatever inflected form of *be* it agrees with (the "-iz" part), relating, for instance,

- *The man **who is** standing on the corner is winking at me*
  and
- *The man standing on the corner is winking at me,*
  thereby also relating most post-nominal phrasal modifiers to equivalent relative clauses.

Another is [*to be*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73491/15299), which applies to infinitive complement clauses, and is governed by the predicate, like the infinitive complementizer it modifies.

Verbs that allow *to be*-Deletion include *declare, consider,* and *feel*.

- *He declared/considered/felt Max (to be) responsible for the accident.*  [optional *to be*]

Verbs that don't allow it include *state, know, hear,* and *intend*.

- *He stated/knew/heard/intended Max to be responsible for the accident.*
- **He stated/knew/heard/intended Max responsible for the accident.* [obligatory *to be*]

A third rule, [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), applies only in main clauses, at the very beginning of a sentence. It deletes any predictable (i.e, meaningless, dummy, auxiliary, grammar particle, etc.) element, producing such normal utterances as

- *Too bad about old Charlie.* [from ***It is*** too bad]
- *No need to get upset about it.* [from ***There is*** no need]

Note that none of these delete copulas alone, but only as part of some complex, usually with a subject and/or other function word being deleted as well. There's no reason to delete a copula until it's not needed any more.

Comment: To be or not - that is the question.

Comment: I didn't even **begin** to address the complications of _to be_-Deletion; Ann Borkin's classic 1973 paper ("_To be_ and not _to be_", _Papers from the Ninth Regional Meeting, Chicago Linguistic Society_ (CLS 9)) produces such examples as _I found Sam appealing_ vs _*I found Sam amusing to Charlie_ and develops some semantic generalizations.

Comment: By "deletion", are you suggesting that in all these constructions, there was once a "be" that was at some point omitted by speakers/writers? If not, you might want to clarify that, because I don't believe that's what happened.

Comment: I thought I had; derivations like this are just a way of linking related constructions, just like _Whiz_-Deletion acknowledges that the identical semantics and syntax of relative clauses and "absolute constructions" is not a coincidence. They are not intended to show what goes on in the mind of any speaker or writer, because frankly nobody knows that. "Deletion" is a metaphor; one could use "insertion", but then one would have to explain why **that** chunk got inserted instead of others, so "deletion" is preferable because it indicates that necessary information is not present.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Okay, that's what I expected, but it may suggest an historical process to people, as with the relation between *may* and the present subjunctive.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yes, it may suggest a historical process to some people. Grammatical terminology, I've found, can suggest just about anything to some people. Which is no reason no to use it, of course, if it's clear enough to others. I don't feel responsible for what other people have or have not learned; only for what I might teach them.