# Adjectives after nouns in descriptions of persons or animals

Tags: nouns, adjectives, postpositive

Am I right that *gray* is an adjective in the following quote?

> ...the light was coming from a flashlight being carried in the mouth of a large black Scottie dog, its *muzzle gray* with age.

Is it common in modern English, or is it an archaic/poetic usage?

Comment: It's common. These are practically the same: Its muzzle *was graying*, its muzzle *graying*, its muzzle *gray*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clause Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307511/clause-question) (“Will we be able to talk?” I asked, my eyes red and swollen from crying, a balled up tissue squeezed tightly between my sweaty palms.) It's an absolute construction (_its muzzle gray with age_).

Comment: It's fairly common in writing, but would sound too formal in everyday conversation.