# "to be" or not "to be"

Tags: expressions

In a sentence like this:

I did not find it *[to be]* ...

1) hard

2) anything hard

3) hard to do

4) anything hard to do

5) etc.

when is including *[to be]* necessary, desired, acceptable, not acceptable?

For example, comparing "I did not find it hard to do" vs. "I did not find it **to be** hard to do" - which one is right? And if both can be right, is the meaning altered by including **to be**?

Comment: This is actually addressed in part of John Lawler's answer to [Does English allow a zero 
 copula in subordinate clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116842/does-english-allow-a-zero-copula-in-subordinate-clauses/116849#116849), the section on to be-deletion.  I don't think the rare occasions when 'anything' is included drop 'to be' so facilely: ??'I did not find it anything that could be considered harmful.' Of course, 'I did not find it anything [for its dinner, poor dog]' is garden-pathy.

Comment: Are you asking about the literal text **to be**, or are you asking about a grammatical conjugation of the verb (*I did not find it **was** hard*)? Note that there is a subtle difference in meaning between those two, so answering that could be important. Can you contrast your example sentences with one where such a verb could *not* be inserted without making it ungrammatical, or where you think it *does* change the meaning?

Comment: @ Jason Bassford Actually I was asking about **to be** specifically. I edited the question to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

Your choice of example is not the best as

(i) negatives usually confuse the issue,

(ii)    “hard” can be the converse of “soft” or “easy”.

(iii)   Anything can be a pronoun/noun – (a) *2020 Greybeard EL&U “Have you anything that will open this bottle?”* or (b) an adverb *2005   A. J. Bruney Microsoft Office Web Components Black Bk. v. 194   *The final data need not look anything similar to the original raw data.*

So if we consider instead, “**I found it difficult.**” and avoid, “**anything**”:

“**I found**…” is a close synonym of “My experience was…”

“My experience was…” has to be followed by a content clause, which is a particular type of clause, usually considered to be a noun clause, which may have several functions.

*(If “My experience was…” is followed directly by an adjective, then the adjective modifies “experience”, whereas with a content clause, the adjective modifies “it” (or whatever the subject is.))*

Thus:

“My experience was that it was difficult,” in which “That it was difficult” is the content clause.

“To find” **also** takes a content clause but, additionally, may also take a reduced content clause. It is reduced to an adjectival complement. *“I found that it was difficult”*, reduces to *“I found it difficult.”*

## Meaning

The slightly greater formality of the full version [[that...] to be] can create a small, but perceptible, difference between the two:
 
*“I found that it was difficult”* – here, the “finding” could be a professional and objective “finding” e.g.

*A: Professor, can we have your opinion of question 7 on the examination for 10-year-old students?”*

*Prof: “I found that it was difficult. It is advanced for young children. It is the sort of question that I would give to 15-year-olds.” (Obviously the professor himself did not find the question difficult.)*

And

*“I found it difficult.”* – Here, it is more likely to be subjective, e.g.

*“John did the job in 2 minutes but I found it difficult.”*