# What semantic meaning does the copula 'be' have in its specifying use?

Tags: semantics, be, copular-verbs, linking-verbs

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 252) says:

> It may be that the *be* of [*Kim is fond of animals*] should be regarded as **semantically empty**, serving the purely syntactic function of carrying the tense inflection, which has to be associated with a verb: note in this connection that translation equivalents in a good number of languages contain no verb. However, there are undoubtedly constructions where *be* **does express a semantic predicate** (e.g. in *The chief culprit was Kim*: see §5.5), and we will simplify by assuming that it does in all cases.

The copula *be* (*is*) of *Kim is fond of animals* is in the ascriptive use in that it ascribes to Kim the property of being fond of animals. By contrast, in *The chief culprit was Kim*, the copula *be* (*was*) is in the specifying use in that it specifies who the chief culprit was.

In the above excerpt, CGEL seems to be saying that the copula *be* in the ascriptive use has no meaning ("semantically empty") whereas that in the specifying use does have some meaning ("does express a semantic predicate").

Assuming this is what CGEL is saying, what semantic meaning does the copula *be* have in its specifying use (that the ascriptive *be* doesn't have)?

Comment: Is this a trick question? In *culprit was Kim*, the "was" specifies the culprit by name.

Comment: @YosefBaskin How does that make it a trick question? Please elaborate. Just so you know, I have no reason whatsoever to post a "trick question".

Comment: So sorry, no disrespect. I meant that I was saying that *be* in its specifying use here does actually specify who. It does not just carry us across a divide, like an empty equal sign.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No apologies necessary, but yours accepted. As for your explanation, do you really think that _be_ itself (rather than the whole structure) carries the meaning of "specifying" in its specifying use? If you do, the same could be said about the ascriptive use, couldn't it? I mean, you could be saying, by the same logic, that the ascriptive _be_ carries the meaning of "ascribing". And if anything has to be "an empty equal sign", it's the specifying _be_, not the ascriptive _be_.

Comment: Just imagine the adverb *specifically* for specifying cases: *The chief culprit was [specifically] Kim*. The specifying *was* means *was specifically*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If _was_ meant _was specifically_, then your sentence would mean "The chief culprit was specifically specifically Kim." Just because you can add the adverb doesn't mean _was_ includes the meaning of the adverb.

Comment: Well, yeah, if you're CGEL, it does.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I am saying that CGEL's specifying *be* includes, roughly, the meaning of an adverb like *specifically*, while its ascriptive *be* includes nothing.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Okay, then, what do you make of the last clause "we will simplify by assuming that it does in all cases" of the excerpt? Are they saying that they will assume that the copula _be_ has a meaning in the specifying use as well as in the ascriptive use?

Comment: Perhaps so. Sounds like they let go of semantic emptiness: _It **may** be that the be of [3i] **should** be regarded as semantically empty..._ (*[3i]*  is a typo by the way.) Paraphrasing: [... **but** let's go ahead and declare *be* — ascriptive or specifying — as expressing a semantic predicate.] So yes, maybe both *be*s carry semantic meaning. Maybe we could say the ascriptive *be* carries the meaning of "to be ascribed the property of": *The chief culprit was hungry.* —> *The chief culprit was ascribed the property of "hungry".*

Comment: @TinfoilHat What do YOU think about all this? Do you subscribe to the idea that the specifying _be_ has its own meaning whereas the ascriptive _be_ doesn't? I personally don't, in part because the specifying use as well as the ascriptive use is subsumed under the copula _be_, which by definition is simply functioning as a link between subject and predicative complement. // If your interpretation of the last clause is correct, I don't understand CGEL's reasoning for treating both uses as expressing "a semantic predicate" while still calling both uses the copula _be_.

Comment: By treating both forms of the copula *be* as carrying meaning, aren't they saying that  any copula *be* expresses a semantic predicate?

Comment: This is a genuinely interesting area of the language.  I think the discussion-in-comments is not a bad way to deal with it.  This is somewhere between grammar and logic.  For example, the copula 'be' has a function in logic.  For example, in  the sentence "The culprit was Kim", 'was' is the 'was' of identity:  "The culprit 'EQUALLED' Kim (or C=K)".  So 'equals' in that sense also 'semantically empty'?  Or are both 'is' and 'equals' both attributive?  Oddly, I found that the Cambridge online dictionary ignore the identity use of the copula.

Comment: In 'John is John' (Tony Blair) there is a wealth of meaning. But possibly opinion-based / ... I'll stop there.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If they're really saying that any copula _be_ expresses a semantic predicate, then they shouldn't be calling _be_ 'copula', because 'copula' by definition simply links subject and predicative complement and is semantically empty. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Tuffy As I understand it, people say the copula _be_ is 'semantically empty' not because 'equal' somehow lacks any meaning but because the copula _be_ is bleached of its original existential meaning.

Comment: @JK2 We seem to be hurtling towards one of language's metaphysical and morphological black holes.

Comment: Or, as Bill Clinton once said, “It depends on what the meaning of the word ‘is’ is.”

Comment: @Tuffy What's so "metaphysical and morphological" about what I said?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth briefly, there is a line according to which logical tautologies are not true but 'analytic' <'true-by-definition'>.  As it stands, there is nothing to indicate whether it is empirically true or false.  If I dig up a potsherd with "Marcus Marcus est" on it, I have no idea what it means.  Maybe the writer is asserting M's right to be speak his mind about someone.  Maybe he is refusing to change the name to be given to his new son.  Maybe ...

Comment: @Tuffy 'Marcus' wasn't used by Beaker-folk.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth :)

Comment: You're supposed to groan.

Comment: Summing up, I would say that CGEL is wrong in trying to simplify by assuming _be_ does "express a semantic predicate" in all cases. The way to simplify is to assume it's always an auxiliary, and that auxiliaries have no semantics.  Hence, in _The chief culprit was Kim_, the proper noun phrase _Kim_ is the predicate, and _was_ is the auxiliary required for all predicate nouns and adjectives. If the sentence is reversed to _Kim was the chief culprit_, then the descriptive noun phrase _the chief culprit_ is the predicate, once again, and  _was_ is an auxiliary, once again. That's much simpler.

Comment: @JohnLawler That may be simpler. But were _Kim_ the predicate, why wouldn't _The chief culprit seems Kim_ work?

Comment: Because that's a different construction, and you can't have a predicate noun or adjective without a _be_ auxiliary, which is present (_seems to be Kim_) but has been deleted by incorrect application of _to be_-deletion in this particular ungrammatical example. That's a fact about where _to be_-deletion is applicable, not about nominal predicates.

Comment: @JohnLawler So why is _to be_-deletion applicable to certain NPs (e.g., _He seems **a nice man**._) but not to others (e.g., *_He seems **Kim**._)? Maybe, certain NPs such as _a nice man_ are indeed the predicate (as you claim them to be), but not the others such as _Kim_?

Comment: Good question. One reason may be the difference in being an identity predicate and being a different kind of nominal predicate; another might be that _seems nice_ has a Raised subject, where as *_seems Kim_ doesn't. There are lots of complications. See Ann Borkin's classic 1973 paper ("To be and not to be", _Papers from the Ninth Regional Meeting_, Chicago Linguistic Society (CLS 9)). The matter [was discussed further here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116849/15299) in ELU.SE.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for recommending the paper. A very interesting read!

Comment: Ann Borkin was a genius. (I only use the past tense because she left linguistics, unfortunately.)

Comment: See also [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571649/specifying-use-of-be).

Comment: @lly That's my own question.

Comment: @JK2 Indeed. My comment isn't specifically directed at you, but making sure that these two show up in each other's side bars.