# Has 'being' been omitted?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, learning

In 2018 about 50,000 people were involved in it, ***most of them part­ time or seasonal staﬀ*** working from small offices in rural areas.

Should there be a "being" between "most of them" and "part time or seasonal staff"? It seems weird when there are only nouns.

thank you for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does English allow a zero copula in subordinate clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116842/does-english-allow-a-zero-copula-in-subordinate-clauses) 'Kai stares up at me from the grave, his eyes hard as obsidian.' /  'Kai stares up at me from the grave, his eyes being hard as obsidian.' Absolute constructions, in which be-deletion is allowed where clarity is not lost.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for your answer . it definitely helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "part-time or *as* seasonal staff"?

Comment: @Joachim - `part time` or `part-time` are both OK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I meant the addition of "as", as in "*most of them were involved in it part time or* as *seasonal staff*".

Comment: You don't need 'as' there, although it would not be wrong.