# Omissibility of "to be" before Noun or Adjective

Tags: complements

I have heard that cognitive verbs such as '*think, believe, consider, suppose, understand, imagine*...etc.' should use '*to be* + noun' or '*to be* + adjective' in the object complement.

> She believed him to be a teacher.

> She considers him (to be) rich.

Yet, there is a saying that '*to be*' cannot be omitted before a noun, but '*to be*' can be omitted before an adjective.

Which one is right?

1. Is *'to be'* always something that can be omitted?
2. Please let me know if there is a subtle difference in meaning between the presence and absence of *'to be'*.

Comment: Hmmm. To quote Hamlet “or not. That is the question.”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does English allow a zero copula in subordinate clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116842/does-english-allow-a-zero-copula-in-subordinate-clauses) John Lawler covers to-be-deletion.

Answer (score 2):

> The verb BE can sometimes be omitted in English without losing
> grammaticality or changing meaning. ([guinlist. press](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/192-when-be-can-be-omitted/))

So, whenever we will agree here that ***be*** is omissible, it would mean that neither grammaticality nor meaning will be changed. The omissibility of *be* between an object and its complement is no easy matter, and it depends on the choice of verbs.

> Grammar errors are likely in this area because *many verbs whose object can be followed by a complement-like noun or adjective either require mention of ***to be*** or forbid it – they do not allow a choice about it.*

As for ***think***, it belongs to the category of those verbs that can, *"at least sometimes"*,  omit ***to be*** before an object complement (whether it is an adjective or noun):

> - Plato ***considered*** *the world* ***(to be)*** *a copy of reality*.
>
> The object here is *the world*, and the object complement is *a copy of reality*. Other verbs usable *at least sometimes* in the same way include many that can have a “descriptive”, “role” or “belief” complement, such as *APPOINT, BELIEVE, DECLARE, ELECT, FIND, JUDGE* and *THINK*.

So whether ***to be*** can or cannot be omitted is not dictated by the fact that it is followed or not by a noun object complement, but by the verb choice.

But I find your example with ***believe*** particular. I don't think *She believed him a teacher* is common, in fact Gngram finds no instance and I think this is because the object complement (a teacher) does not really express opinion. GNgram did find such instances:

> She believed him a monster.

Here opinion is much stronger.
***Consider*** seems to be [much more prone](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=believed%20him%20a%20monster%2Cbelieved%20him%20a%20teacher%2C%20considered%20him%20a%20monster%2Cconsidered%20him%20a%20teacher&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelieved%20him%20a%20monster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20him%20a%20monster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsidered%20him%20a%20teacher%3B%2Cc0) to omiss ***to be***:

[image]

CONCLUSION: It would be easy to have a set rule and just follow it, but this is one more proof that English does not work this way.  The omissibility of *to be* is dictated by verb choice, by the element of opinion, but also by the behaviour of each verb in part. Also, I think it would be fair to say that the omission of ***to be*** before adjectives is much more common than before nouns, but the latter can and does sometimes occur within the boundaries of grammaticality.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your two hypotheses:

> A. When followed by 'Object (O) + *to be* + Object Complement (OC)', cognitive verbs such as *think, believe, consider, suppose, understand, imagine,* etc. **should** use a noun phrase (NP) or an adjective phrase (AdjP) as OC.

> B. In the structure 'cognitive verb + O + *to be* + OC', *to be* cannot be omitted when OC = NP, but can be omitted when OC = AdjP.

Before answering the question, let me make it clear that hypotheses A and B are not terribly accurate. Firstly, those verbs are so called not because of their syntactic behaviors but because of their semantics. Just because you can lump them together under the same semantic group doesn't mean that their syntactic behavior will be the same.

For example, *think* can rarely be followed by 'O + *to be* + OC':

> (1) ?*She thought him to be a teacher.*

(1) is unidiomatic at best and can be thought of as a counterexample of hypothesis A.

Hypothesis B presumes that the structure with *to be* is somehow more readily allowed than the one without. But that presumption is wrong in the case of *think*:

> (1') *She thought him a teacher.*

Although (1) is ill-formed, (1') is well-formed albeit less idiomatic than (1''):

> (1'') *She thought he was a teacher.*

Likewise:

> (2) ?*She thought him to be rich.*
>
> (2') *She thought him rich.*
>
> (2'') *She thought he was rich.*

So it's not like that the structure with *to be* is always possible and that you only have to figure out when you can omit *to be*.

Having said all that, in order to answer your question, let's just focus on those verbs that allow the structure 'cognitive verb + O + *to be* + OC' with or without *to be*.

In (3)-(5) and (3')-(5'), an AdjP can be OC, but an NP can be OC unless the NP is referential (i.e., referring to a particular person, thing, etc.)

> (3) *She considers him to be rich/a teacher/Steve Jobs.*
>
> (4) *She supposes him to be rich/a teacher/Steve Jobs.*
>
> (5) *She imagines him to be rich/a teacher/Steve Jobs.*

> (3') *She considers him rich/a teacher/??Steve Jobs.*
>
> (4') *She supposes him rich/a teacher/??Steve Jobs.*
>
> (5') *She imagines him rich/a teacher/??Steve Jobs.*

Since *Steve Jobs* refers to a particular person, *to be* is required.

Comment: [Ann Borkin's paper](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/cls/pcls/1973/00000009/00000001/art00005?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf) might be of some use (or it might not).