# Clause in sentence

Tags: clauses, extraposition, to-be-deletion

> John found it surprising that Wayne played the tuba.

*That Wayne played the tuba* is the clause, but what kind is it? I am completely stuck on this and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence has been done things to.

There are actually three clauses here, with 3 predicates: *find, (be) surprising,* and *play*.
*Find* takes an infinitive object complement, and *(be) surprising* takes a tensed subject *that*-clause.

> John found [[that Wayne played the tuba] **to be** surprising]
> ==>  [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299)
> John found [**it** to be surprising [that Wayne played the tuba]]
> ==> [*to be*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73491/15299)
> John found it surprising [that Wayne played the tuba].

*That Wayne played the tuba* is the subject complement clause of *to be surprising*.
The dummy subject *it* gets inserted by Extraposition, and then *to be*-Deletion does the rest.

To answer the question, *that Wayne played the tuba* is **all** of the following:

- **a subordinate clause** (since it's not the main clause)
- **a subject clause** (since it's the subject of *(be) surprising*)
- **a noun clause** (since it's a subject, it acts as a noun)
- **a tensed clause** (since it has a tensed main verb *played*)
- **a *that*-clause** (since it uses the tensed clause complementizer *that*)
- **an extraposed clause** (since it was moved by Extraposition)

It is not, however, an adverbial clause of any kind.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is a [dependent adverbial clause.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause).

*That Wayne played the tuba* modifies *found it surprising*.