# Is it correct to say "I think sth important"?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, subordinate-clauses, transitivity

I know that I can say:

> I consider this idea important.
>   I deem this film stupid.
>   I regard my health as important.

But can I say:

> I think money/health/love/etc. important.

Or does it have to be:

> I think money/health/love/etc. is important.

Or are both okay?

Comment: Not normally. That would require B-Raising and _To be_-Deletion to both apply to a complement of _think_. That doesn't occur, though there may be vestiges of it in more complex constructions. [Verbs that mean the same thing like _believe_,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73491/15299) as you point out, work this way. But _think_ doesn't; verbs often vary in this kind of syntactic possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few specialized constructions of this sort:

> We do not think it necessary to go. ("think it A" where "A" is an adjective)
>
> Some people do not think it important to be thrifty. (same as above)
>
> She did not wish him to think it possible. (same as above)
>
> I think it fair that ... (same as above)
>
> I thought it over carefully. ("think it over" is a fixed phrasal verb)

It seems that for "think", one cannot use it with two 'objects' as in "think X Y", and only in the idiomatic construction "think it X" where "it" can only refer to a concept or idea, not physical things.

Comment: Should "I thought it carefully over" have an asterisk to indicate that it's not used? *✲I thought it carefully over.* Phrasal verbs are normally not split: *I thought it over carefully.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach: There is a tendency not to split phrasal verbs, but it does happen, and I as a native speaker did not find anything wrong with the particular wording I used, though after reading yours I agree that your version is more frequent. For example, consider "got/stood straight up from the seat", "came right back to me", "come completely apart", "life goes straight on". I admit that these examples all have the inserted adverb having a certain type of semantic meaning, but I'm not sure people really don't use other types of adverbs this way.