# "Why is it that..." relative clause?

Tags: parts-of-speech, relative-clauses, clauses, subjects, dependent-clause

It would be great if someone could explain this sentence structure to me:

"Why is it that you don't like me?"

I don't understand how all of the components come together.
What is the link between it and that?
Is "that you don't like me" a relative clause that modifies "it"?
Is "it" the subject?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> - *Why is it that you don't like me?*

Well, it's not surprising that this sentence confuses you. This sentence has been done things to.

To unpack this sentence, you start from the inside, like algebra. There is a tensed subordinate clause

- *you don't like me*

at the end of the sentence, where it is the focus of attention.

It is introduced by [a *That*-complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73491/15299) (this form of *that* does not refer to anything, and is not a relative pronoun), which is normal, though often deleted, before tensed complement clauses like this one.  Note that this clause does not indicate a reason for this dislike; it does not contain a reason adverb. But it could:

- *that you don't like me **because ...***

This, in turn, is chopped up by an *It*-cleft construction

- *It is **because ...** that you don't like me*.

that leaves a dummy subject *it* (again, no reference; it's like *it* in *It's raining*).

To find out what this reason ("because ...") might be, one asks a *Wh*-question.  *Why* is the *Wh*-word that refers to a *reason*. To form a *Wh*-question, one inverts the subject (dummy *it*) and the auxiliary (*is*), and puts the appropriate *Wh*-word in front of the auxiliary.

- **Why is it** that you don't like me?

and adds a question mark in print (but in speech, *Wh*-questions have no question intonation the way yes/no question do -- they sound just like statements).

There was a lot of cutting and folding in that sentence; syntax like that reminds me of origami.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I'm still a bit confused. "You don't like me" isn't an independent clause?

Comment: The sentence _You don't like me_, like all full sentences, is an independent clause. The clause _you don't like me_ in the sentence _Why is it that you don't like me?_ is a dependent clause because it's embedded in a larger full sentence. It depends on the rest of the sentence; it's not independent. OK?

Comment: @ John Lawler,  It seems like this.  " You don't like me because ..."  transforms into an emphatic sentence " It is because ... that you don't like me".  Then, change the latter into a wh-question by using "why" to take the place of the clause " because..."; it is " Why is it that you don't like me?".