# He considers that X is Y. vs He thinks that X is Y

Tags: verbs, american-english, british-english

The following verb in sentence 1 strikes me as strange when it has the same meaning as in sentences 2 and 3 below.

1. He considers that blue cheese is delicious.
2. He thinks that blue cheese is delicious.
3. He believes that blue cheese is delicious.

Is sentence 1 acceptable? Is it maybe acceptable in British English but not in American English?

Comment: No, sentence 1 is not acceptable.  It has to be “He considers blue cheese delicious”.

Answer (score 2):

**Acceptable** is a loaded term.

Like @tchrist, I would not use sentence 1 in the form proposed. I would probably change it to "He finds blue cheese delicious." on the grounds of euphony.

But there is a spectrum of reactions from *that sounds clumsy* to *that breaches several principles of grammar and syntax*. Where you place "acceptable" within that span is obviously a very personal opinion. It is probably related to whether you consider "has to be" an acceptable replacement for "must be".

Answer (score 2):

This one gets [a bit complicated](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59387/2637). Consider

> 1. He considers blue cheese to be delicious. [(618)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20thinks%20you%20to%20be%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20considers%20you%20to%20be%22&oq=%22he%20considers%20you%20to%20be%22&gs_l=serp.3...29003.32582.2.32989.15.15.0.0.0.1.152.1020.14j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.esHZs6HhALU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6744cf75155b6f67&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917)
> 2. He thinks blue cheese to be delicious. [(8)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20thinks%20you%20to%20be%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20thinks%20you%20to%20be%22&oq=%22he%20thinks%20you%20to%20be%22&gs_l=serp.3...188728.191510.1.192118.14.14.0.0.0.0.119.1018.12j2.14.0...0.0...1c.1.dvgSLfsoq8U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6744cf75155b6f67&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917)
> 3. He believes blue cheese to be delicious. [(2130)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20thinks%20you%20to%20be%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20believes%20you%20to%20be%22&oq=%22he%20believes%20you%20to%20be%22&gs_l=serp.3...6172.12196.0.13274.14.14.0.0.0.0.150.939.13j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.FEMFT5H8SDU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=6744cf75155b6f67&bpcl=37189454&biw=1464&bih=917)

(OP's *"blue cheese"* was a bit too unusual to deliver a reasonable number of hits in Google Books, so I got the usage figures above by substituting *"you"*).

As per the first link above, if you *think something [to be true]*, that can often imply *the thing is only (or even, **axiomatically**) true by virtue of your opinion*. But if you *believe it [to be true]*, your opinion has no effect on the truth of the thing itself.

So - if you ***think** blue cheese is delicious*, you're saying *you* like it. If you ***believe** it's delicious*, you're saying it's inherently delicious, so everyone else should like it too.

As the usage figures show, *consider* falls somewhere somewhere between *think* and *believe* in terms of how much your opinion thus expressed  can affect the facts (mostly it can't).

Comment: "He believes that blue cheese is delicious" can also mean that he has never tasted it, but thinks it might be.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I think that implication is pretty much inherent in the contrast I make above. If he *thinks* it's delicious, that could be a matter of personal taste - his evaluation can't be "proved" right or wrong. But if he *believes* so, this may be on the flimsiest of evidence (perhaps he's never even *seen* blue cheese, but he trusts the judgement of a friend who says it's really good). Of course, there are many other contexts where the verbs are effectively equivalent. And yet more contexts where *other* distinctions can be made (but I think mine is the most significant, obviously! :)

Comment: Generally, "think" is stronger than "believe", except when talking about things we normally expect people to have strong beliefs about. If you say someone "believes" something, it suggests something weaker than knowledge. There's a continuum of words like this: doubt, suspect, believe, think, know.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I don't see "strength" as a relevant factor in our aversion to *thinking [noun] to be [adjective]*, and whatever that tells us about the difference between *thinking* and *believing*. And I'm not automatically inclined to rate *thinking* as stronger in general. For example, it's quite possible to say: *"You're really just a closet agnostic! You might **think** God exists, but you don't really **believe** in Him like I do!"*. IMHO, *believe* is often closer to *know* than *think* is.

Answer (score 1):

When I hear the the phrase "X considers Y," I tend to think it usually means something closer to "ponders." If it were phrased in a more passive voice, e.g. "X is considered Y by Z," it would sound more like the idea the other sentences are trying to get across.

Then again, "He considers blue cheese to be delicious" sounds fine to me, so it might just be that "considers that" is a bizarre-sounding way to format it.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that, although it's correct, it comes across as "He ponders the idea that blue cheese is delicious."

Comment: I think this is wide of the mark. It's true "consider" can mean *ponder, muse upon*, but in OP's specific context that wouldn't be a normal interpretation. You'd probably have to say something like *"He considers the proposition that blue cheese might be delicious"* to get the idea across.