# Reflexive pronouns and understood "to be"

Tags: phrases, pronouns, infinitives

So, I've got a fairly straightforward sentence:

> Poe did not think himself a writer of inferior material.

It is my understanding that "a writer of inferior material" is the object of the understood infinitive "to be," and that the sentence is saying that, in simpler terms, "Poe did not think that he (Poe) was a writer of inferior material."

But *how does one break this sentence down into parts of sentence*?

What I've got so far: *Poe* is the subject; *did think* is the simple predicate. My teacher said that "himself" was a reflexive pronoun serving as the direct object, or in other words that...erm..."Poe thought himself." This doesn't make much sense to me, since it seems like Poe is serving as more of an "indirect-object-esque-but-not-really" thing. Could someone please explain (and tie that infinitive in there too ;) )? Thanks!

Comment: No the noun phrase _a writer of inferior material_ is not the object of the understood infinitive _to be_. It's the predicate. The _be_ form is simply the auxiliary verb required for predicate nouns and adjectives (_he is a doctor, he is tired_). Predicates aren't objects, intransitive verbs don't have objects, and _be_ is certainly intransitive. You're right about most of it, though.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo I'm asking what the different parts of sentence (e.g., subject, predicate, direct object, indirect object, etc.) are in this sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Sorry, I think I've lost you. So Poe thinks...what? What does Poe think? (In relationship to parts of a sentence...he thinks "a writer of inferior material"? So how does "himself" come into play?) Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: [I think *you lost me*, that is]

Comment: possible duplicate of [I think him to be about 50 or I think he is about 50?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/i-think-him-to-be-about-50-or-i-think-he-is-about-50)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three kinds of clauses with lexical verbs in them.

1. Some clauses have a subject, a direct object, **and** an indirect object.
   **Three** different noun phrase arguments.

   - ***Mike*** told **Billy the story**.
     **Mary** sent **the cake** to **Sylvia**.
     These are called Bitransitive clauses.
     There are not very many verbs like *tell* and *send*,
     and most of them have to do with transfer.
2. Some clauses have a subject **and** a direct object, but no indirect object.
   **Two** different noun phrase arguments.

   - ***Mike*** saw **Billy**.
     **Mary** hates **Sylvia**.
     These are called Transitive clauses.
     There are a lot of verbs that can occur in transitive clauses, of many different kinds.
3. Some clauses only have a subject, but no object of any kind.
   Only **one** noun phrase argument.

   - ***Mike*** ran yesterday.
     **Mary** is sleeping now.
     These are called Intransitive clauses.
     There are a lot of verbs that can occur intransitively, too.
     Frequently one verb can swing both ways.

Now, *think* can be transitive or intransitive. It's an active verb semantically, and always requires an agent subject; if possible, a sapient subject. I.e, human. Intransitively, it can just mean to cerebrate or vacillate, mentally or emotionally. The focus of thought is often represented with *about*. That's the intransitive use of *think*; or at least one of them.

But the presenting sentence

- *Poe did not think himself a writer of inferior material.*

is transitive. **This** use of *think* is equivalent to *consider* or *believe*, and means, roughly, 'to have an opinion on X as Y'. And you're correct that the predictable phrase *to be* has been deleted. All of these except the last one are examples of [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

- *Poe did not think himself **to be** a writer of inferior material.*  (B-Raising)
- *Poe did not consider himself **to be** a writer of inferior material.* (B-Raising)
- *Poe did not believe himself **to be** a writer of inferior material.*  (B-Raising)
- *Poe did not have an opinion of himself as a writer of inferior material.*  (Not B-Raising)

Briefly, that means that the real object of *think* is the infinitive clause  *(for) Poe to be a writer...*
and its Subject, *Poe*, gets "lifted up" and reinterpreted as the Object of *think*
(or *believe*, or *consider*, or any other B-Raising verb).
Since *Poe* is now the object of a transitive clause,
and *Poe* is also the (co-referential) subject of the same clause,
the rules require that the object *Poe* has to appear as a reflexive pronoun.

That's all. The reflexive is automatic, given that the subject and object are co-referential.

Answer (score 1):

Subject: Poe.  Verb: think.  Object: Poe (again).

You could expand it to "Poe did not think of Poe a writer of inferior material."  Adding the preposition clarifies the idea.  "About" wold also work.

Another question to the Forum:  is that "of" part of a prepositional phrase?

Comment: Yes, _of_ is a preposition and always is a part of a prepositional phrase. Its object may be indefinite, or deleted, or moved, but there is always some object. _Of_ doesn't mean anything more than the relationship between its object and the noun phrase it modifies.

Comment: Okay, so what is *a writer of inferior material*?

Comment: _A writer of inferior material_ is a person who writes inferior material. _Writer_ is a nominalization of the subject of _write_, but nouns can't have objects, so the object of _write_ gets marked with _of_.