# Usage of “to find (noun) (adj)”

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage, infinitives, zero-copula

I am a native speaker of German, and I often see the English verb *find* being used like its German cognate *finden*. For example:

> My students and I find your platform very useful and very appealing
>   visually, as well. — [Source](http://un.iversity.org/pages/testimonials)

This just *feels* wrong to me. Shouldn’t it be something like:

> My students and I find your platform **to be** very useful and very appealing visually, as well.

Can you use *find* like that?

Comment: You **can** use _find_ like that. Normally, you'd be correct. But _find_ is a member of a class of "small verbs" (including _make, get, come,_ and _go_) that allow infinitives without _to_, just like modal auxiliaries do. They're halfway toward becoming auxiliary verbs, and they're pretty bleached of meaning.

Comment: And you're more likely to be identified as a native English speaker if you use the first variant you cite (but possibly that would be undesirable?) Though 'My students and I find your platform very useful, and also very appealing visually' is probably even more idiomatic.

Comment: @JohnLawler Eh? OP cites uses with *no verb*, not with a bare infinitive. I'm having trouble thinking of *find* with a bare infinitive rather than an *-ing* form.

Comment: @StoneyB: Sorry, wrong piece of comment. I meant to say that small verbs also govern _to be_-Deletion, and that this does come from the (also grammatical) _find X to be Y_ construction, via [B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). But I got distracted and mentioned a different peculiarity that wasn't relevant here. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Can you add this information in an answer? It seems to adequately answer the question.

Comment: and... for me "very appealing visually" _feels_ wrong, "visually very appealing" sounds better :)

Comment: @RegDwight, I think I may have misunderstood the OP's request: "Can you use *to find* like that?" as to whether his second variant is acceptable. Instead, Shoe's post is confirming the validity of the first usage. Can I make an edit to the bounty? As I am curious to know about the former, and nobody has really touched that aspect.

Comment: Closely related is [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/59387/2637), which considers various possibilities of *"I think/believe/find/etc. **X**"*. Where ***X*** may be in the form *your platform **to be** useful*, or *your platform **is** useful*. I offered a bounty there, but it didn't seem to bring the matter to a definitive conclusion.

Comment: Personally, I think there's a subtle difference between (a juror) saying "I find him to be guilty", and (anyone) saying "I find Joyce's *Finnegans Wake* to be incomprehensible". Specifically, it's to do with the fact that *...to be...* in such constructions seems to imply that the "finding" is something *created/made true* by the speaker (so it works better in the "juror" context for me).

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Could you be more specific in what you're looking for in an answer? I'm not sure what's "first" or "former" anymore. There are a number of different possible verbs and constructions like _find_ `NP` _(to be)_ `PredAdj`.

Comment: @JohnLawler :1)*"I find your platform very useful"*  2) *"I find your platform **to be** very useful"* Q: *"Can you use find like that?"* I am interested in No2, and I interpreted the OP's question as asking confirmation whether find + object + to be is acceptable. So far the posted answers have concentrated on whether No1 is "natural" and "correct". Something which I already knew.

Comment: _To-be_-Deletion is optional with _find_; the DO is clearly raised from the Su of the infinitive clause, and deleting the remaining infinitive mark is common enough with small verbs, as I said. There really isn't any syntactic or semantic difference between the _to-be_-deleted ones (type 2) and the undeleted ones (type 1). It's just a lexical vagary, an auxiliary (for the PredAdj) that's no longer necessary since only the VP is left after Raising, and the VP is just _to be_ + Adj. Is there some special difficulty?

Comment: Thank you @JohnLawler. Much appreciated, would it be fair to say that type 2 is outdated?

Comment: Not as far as I know. More depends on how many syllables one wants to use, which affects how many milliseconds one's addressee has to comprehend the structure.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You should award the bounty to Nordquist: [verbless clause](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/verblessclauseterm.htm)

Comment: @TaliaFord why didn't you post it as an answer? I see no difference in copying an informative answer from a reputable source than someone copy and pasting from OED. You're right about Nordquist, but he's not an ELU user. :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm having some qualms about picking up that bounty. The thing is, I didn't do any research for this q and wasn't clear on the answer until I stumbled upon Nordquist's entry while I was looking up info for some other q. It was only then that I remembered this one. But, you're right; somebody oughta shoulda gotta do it. I think it should be you. The q gets deigned with a nifty answer, no bounty is undeservedly awarded, and all is well in the Kingdom of God.

Comment: I didn't do any research, I was hoping others would. Once I answered my own question because nobody had answered it satisfactorily and I immediately got downvoted! Maybe they thought I was acting out of hubris, who knows?! @TaliaFord you found a good source, you posted the link now post the answer. Think about it at least.

Comment: @Mary-Lou, The problem as I see it is that you have used the comments to ask a follow-up question to the OP's original question. Therefore Thalia's answer does not seem to fit as a separate answer on this page. Maybe you could consider asking your question as a separate question; then Thalia can post her answer to it there (and pick up the bounty).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Whoever downvoted you for answering your own q, which is a practice SE not only permits but also encourages, should have their acct suspended. As for answering your subquestion, I agree with Shoe. You may want to start another one; this one is about the 1st sentence only.But be assured, the to-infinitive clause in the 2nd S is grammatical.More proofs: [to find something to be true](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/find), [find X [to be] Y](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.7153&rep=rep1&type=pdf), http://books.google.com/books?id=EXwdvQgObVIC&pg=PA288

Comment: @TaliaFord I cannot know if that was the motivation for the downvote, maybe I went too much in detail, maybe they thought the images I posted were superfluous. I don't know. I have given up asking and thinking about such matters. It's a great pity you haven't posted an answer, it would give a more complete picture. So be it. I can neither force nor tempt you it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the *Cambridge Grammar of English* (p523) under the heading *Complex Transitive Complementation*:

> Many common verbs may be used with a direct object followed by an
>   adjective phrase acting as an object complement.

The GCE includes the example:

> We found the garden slightly disappointing.

This corresponds to the OP's first sentence:

> My students and I find your platform very useful ...

which is consequently grammatical.

Among the other verbs listed by the CGE that can be followed by a direct object and object complement are: *keep* and *make*. CGE examples:

> I must keep dad's (sic) dinner warm.
>
> The whole of mankind makes me angry.

Comment: @Mari-Lou. I interpreted the OP's question _Can you use to find like that?_ as applying to the first sentence, which he or she finds weird (!) and not to the second one. Maybe this could be  clarified.

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted the OP's question. So I'll make it my own. Is "find + noun + to be" possible and acceptable?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to ask a separate question about "find + noun + to be". The Comments section is probably not the best place for considered answers.

Comment: My question was aimed at you :) I just have this niggling doubt, btw I do like your answer.

Comment: Off the top of my head I suspect that _to be_ is more likely to be inserted if the direct object is a heavy noun phrase whose head is distant from its object complement. So, _I find this usage unobjectionable_ is unproblematic (and for me preferable to _I find this usage to be unobjectionable_), whereas _I find the way that he always tries to gather peas on the top of his fork when eating out very irritating_ niggles somewhat. But I really think this deserves a question in its own right.

Comment: And you made that last sentence off the top of your head?! :)

Comment: No, the suspicion was off the top of my head, but not the example sentence - although I do have someone specific in mind!

Comment: I was mostly interested whether this is correct English and not a 'Germanism'. I much enjoyed all the answers and different interpretations. Thanks!

Comment: @phw No. It's not a Germanism. English has both versions and there are also other similar cases in English.

Answer (score 1):

If your sentence is just :

> I find your platform very useful and very appealing visually, as well.

then we can use "to be",

> I find your platform to be very useful and very appealing visually, as well.

But, if you are going to include "My students", then

> My students and I find your platform very useful and very appealing visually, as well.

is much appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unconvinced by Edwin Ashworth's suggestion that the first variant is more likely to have you accepted as a native speaker. I find the first variant to be very awkward although I accept that a sizeable proportion of native speakers (though not the majority, I think) will use it.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth is correct. I was quite surprised when I looked at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=find+it+to+be+useful%2Cfind+it+useful&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfind%20it%20to%20be%20useful%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfind%20it%20useful%3B%2Cc0) to find the ***second variant*** virtually unused.

Answer (score 0):

As a native (British) English speaker, I find the first form far more natural, but I might use the second in very formal writing. (And without even thinking about it, I realise that I used the first form in that sentence!)